# Using a list as arguments for a function in OCaml

Tags: python, ocaml

I am currently trying to learn OCaml. And I am searching for the equivalent of this python code:

```
f(*l[:n])
```

I thought I'd try to write a function that emulates this behavior, but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
let rec arg_supply f xs n =
    if n = 0 then
        f
    else
        match xs with
        | x :: remainder -> arg_supply (f x) remainder (n - 1);;
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
'b -> 'a
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'b -> 'a
```

Any help is appreciated, be it a way to get my function working, or another way to supply the first n elements of a list to a function as arguments.

Edit: `n` is the amount of arguments needed to call the function, and constant because of it.

Edit: This one doesn't work either.

```
type ('a, 'r) as_value = ASFunction of ('a -> ('a, 'r) as_value) | ASReturnValue of 'r;;

let rec _arg_supply f_or_rval xs n =
    if n = 0 then
        f_or_rval
    else
        match f_or_rval with
        | ASFunction func -> (
            match xs with
                | x :: r ->  _arg_supply (func x) r (n - 1)
                | _ -> failwith "too few arguments for f"
        )
        | ASReturnValue out -> out;;
```

Comment: You can't do that. The type of `arg_supply` would have to depend on the runtime value of `n`.

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Could you explain what you really want to do instead ?

Comment: @Drup I want to call a function, where my arguments are in a list, without having to write `name_of_the_function (List.nth li 0) (List.nth li 1) (List.nth li 2)...`.
And I know that the solution I tried wouldn't help even if it worked, because the return type would have to be ASFunction, wich it isn't. But I could "expand" my function to fit this type.

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* you want this. What is the use case ?

Comment: And it particular, it doesn't explain why just passing the list `li` directly doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @Drup I could give it the list, but the problem is, that I use currying, and I don't know if the compiler manages to optimize it accordingly. An additional problem would be that I would have to call the function with a list even when I am not extracting the data from one. Currently I get the elements by using List.nth for every argument.

Comment: Are you implementing an evaluator for a DSL where functions have variable arity?

Comment: @coredump No. I am building a node-based animation software, where values can also be functions. And I have created some functions in the form `let circle_color_at radius fill stroke stroke_width inputs = let x = List.nth inputs 0 and y = List.nth inputs 1 ...`, and I call those without x and y in the run function of the node: `let circle_run inputs = FunctionValue (circle_color_at (List.nth inputs 0) (List.nth inputs 1) (List.nth inputs 2) (List.nth inputs 3))`

Answer (score 3):

Your Python function `f` is being passed different numbers of arguments, depending on the value of `n`. This can't be expressed in OCaml. Functions take a statically fixed number of arguments (i.e., you can tell the number of arguments by reading the source code).

The way to pass different numbers of arguments to an OCaml function is to pass a list, corresponding to the Python code `f(l[:n])`.

(It's more accurate to say that an OCaml function takes one argument, but this is a discussion for another time.)

**Update**

If `n` is actually a constant, let's say it's 3. Then you can do something like the following:

```
 match l with
 | a :: b :: c :: _ -> f a b c
 | _ -> failwith "too few arguments for f"
```

**Update 2**

Here's another way to look at what you want to do. You want to write a function, let's call it `apply`, that works like this:

```
let apply f xs =
    . . .
```

The idea is that `apply` calls the function `f`, giving it arguments from the list `xs`.

OCaml is a strongly typed language, so we should be able to give a type for `f` and for `xs`. What is the type of `f`? You want it to be a function of `n` arguments, where `n` is the length of `xs`. I.e., `n` is not a constant! But there is no such type in OCaml. Any function type has a fixed, static number of parameters. Since there's no OCaml type for `f`, you can't write the function `apply`. You can write a series of functions `apply1`, `apply2`, and so on. Note that each of these functions has a different type. If you don't mind calling the correct one for each different function `f`, that would work.

It's fairly likely that you can restructure your problem to work with OCaml's typing rather than struggling with it. I stand by my comments on strong typing: once you get used to strong typing, it's very hard to give up the benefits and go back to languages with little (or no) typing support.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify it in my question. n is the amount of arguments needed for f, and constant. Thats the reason for the `[:n]` thing.

Comment: I tend to doubt that `n` is actually a constant. Otherwise you would write something like f(*l[:3]). But it's not hard to write code for any given value of `n`. See **update** above.

Comment: Wich would mean that I should create arg_supply_1, arg_supply_2, ...
This isn't what I actually want. It would be ok if I wouldn't need to every one of those.

Comment: Well, you said `n` was a constant, so there should be just one function. :-) If possible, you should pass a list to your functions. There are tradeoffs with strong typing, but after you get used to it it's very hard to go back. You don't want to use patterns from languages with looser type systems (if any).

Comment: I meant that `n` is constant for every call. So if it would be possible to create a "template" that creates all those functions `arg_supply_1`, `arg_supply_2`, ...; it would solve my problem.